# Why Random constructor in c# assigns Seed parameter in the end of the method?

Tags: c#, random, assignment-operator, redundancy

I checked source code of Random class of .Net [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,92e3cf6e56571d5a,references). What surprises me is the last line

```
  public Random(int Seed) {
    int ii;
    int mj, mk;

    //Initialize our Seed array.
    //This algorithm comes from Numerical Recipes in C (2nd Ed.)
    int subtraction = (Seed == Int32.MinValue) ? Int32.MaxValue : Math.Abs(Seed);
    mj = MSEED - subtraction;
    SeedArray[55]=mj;
    mk=1;
    for (int i=1; i<55; i++) {  //Apparently the range [1..55] is special (Knuth) and so we're wasting the 0'th position.
      ii = (21*i)%55;
      SeedArray[ii]=mk;
      mk = mj - mk;
      if (mk<0) mk+=MBIG;
      mj=SeedArray[ii];
    }
    for (int k=1; k<5; k++) {
      for (int i=1; i<56; i++) {
    SeedArray[i] -= SeedArray[1+(i+30)%55];
    if (SeedArray[i]<0) SeedArray[i]+=MBIG;
      }
    }
    inext=0;
    inextp = 21;
    Seed = 1;
  }
```

What is the purpose of assigning parameter in the end of the method?

Comment: Why not? I have no idea why they chose to do that but I also see no reason why not.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen *Why not?* Because it does nothing.

Comment: I see that now, I mistakenly assumed it was a property that was being set, I see now that it is the parameter.

Comment: Indeed, the casing puts you off here, but it really has no use. Guess it was an intern writing that code ;)

Comment: Agreed, I checked the decompiled code to make sure this wasn't just a reference source oddity but it's in there as well.

Comment: *//This algorithm comes from Numerical Recipes in C (2nd Ed.)* - perhaps therin the last line is `*seed = 1;` - I checked  - it is - its a drop in copy with some tweaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `Seed` parameter is not being passed by `ref` and `int` is a value type, then the last line has no effect whatsoever.

Thanks to @Alex K for pointing that out, after checking the algorithm they adapted in *Numerical Recipes in C*, indeed they copied and pasted that last line:

```
if ( * idum < 0 || iff == 0) {
  Initialization.
  iff = 1;
  mj = labs(MSEED - labs( * idum));
  Initialize ma[55] using the seed idum and the
  mj %= MBIG;
  large number MSEED.
  ma[55] = mj;
  mk = 1;
  for (i = 1; i <= 54; i++) {
    ii = (21 * i) % 55;
    ma[ii] = mk;
    mk = mj - mk;
    if (mk < MZ) mk += MBIG;
    mj = ma[ii];
  }
  for (k = 1; k <= 4; k++)
    (i = 1; i <= 55; i++) {
    ator.”
    ma[i] -= ma[1 + (i + 30) % 55];
    if (ma[i] < MZ) ma[i] += MBIG;
  }
  inext = 0;
  inextp = 31;
  * idum = 1;
}
```

Comment: I sure hope they paid more attention to the crypto random stuff than they did to this slightly embarrassing copy/paste job.

Answer (score 2):

It is a faulty translation of the `float rand3(long *idum)` function from the book [*Numerical Recipies in C (2nd Edition)*](https://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf) (p. 283). There is this part to initialize the seed array (`idum` is the seed parameter):

```
iff=1;
mj=labs(MSEED-labs(*idum)); 
mj %= MBIG; large number MSEED.
ma[55]=mj;
mk=1;
for (i=1;i<=54;i++) { 
    ii=(21*i) % 55;
    ma[ii]=mk; 
    mk=mj-mk;
    if (mk < MZ) mk += MBIG;
        mj=ma[ii];
}
for (k=1;k<=4;k++)
    (i=1;i<=55;i++) { 
        ma[i] -= ma[1+(i+30) % 55];
       if (ma[i] < MZ) ma[i] += MBIG;
    }
inext=0; 
inextp=31;
*idum=1;
```

The translator did not set the seed parameter to `ref`. Thus the line has no effect in the C# translation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no use in setting `Seed` there. It is a local value type variable with no use after the constructor ended.

I guess it is just a fault.